# Path difference between ../ and ./

Tags: linux, path

Could anyone explain the difference between ../ and ./ please.

```
../system
./system
```

My understanding is that `../` is the root directory.

But I don't know what `./`means.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`./` means the current directory

`../` means the parent of the current directory, not the root directory

`/` is the root directory

`myfile.text` is in the current directory, as is `./myfile.text`

`../myfile.text` is one level above you and `/myfile.text` lives in your root directory.

Comment: To add more detail for future readers: ~/ is your home directory, and you can combine the operators above: ../../file would be a file two directories below.

Comment: `.` and `..` are provided by the filesystem, and so available everywhere. But `~` is interpreted by the shell, and so can only be used in shell command lines; other programs will treat it as a literal filename.

Answer (score 7):

```
. Current Directoy

.. Parent Directory
```

`./system` means, a `directory/file` called system in the current directory.

Comment: However, there would be little use preceding "system" with a "./" if it is a directory -- it's probably an executable. In UNIX/Linux systems, the current directory is not included in the search path for executables, so to run an executable in the current directory, you would preced it with "./"

Answer (score 4):

The . and .. are relative directories to your current location.

The . is the current directory. eg "this".
The .. is the previous directory. eg "this.parent".

Answer (score 3):

- . is the current directory
- .. is the parent directory of the current directory

... which means:

- ./system is the subdirectory or file called "system" of the current directory
- ../system is the subdirectory or file called "system" of the parent directory, which makes it a sibling of the current directory.

Comment: However, there would be little use preceding "system" with a "./" if it is a directory -- it's probably an executable. In UNIX/Linux systems, the current directory is not included in the search path for executables, so to run an executable in the current directory, you would preced it with "./"

Comment: Oh yeah it might be a regular file as well.

Answer (score 1):

../ is the directory above this one

./ is the current directory

Answer (score 1):

./ means the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think ,
`./ and .` are the same, they mean **current directory**. While `../` means first **layer parent directory.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).